# connecting to external database

Tags: android

Someone tell me how can we build an application in android so that we enter value in android but the value should be stored in external database like mysql.I am new to this so can anyone give the full coding for that.

Comment: try searching for tutorials on how to integrate sqlite db

Answer (score 0):

Either expose your database via a web API (search for RESTful) and access it via HTTP, or access it directly using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

using external database through android directly not possible .it is possible using web services or java server Application(means servlet)

we can send the values from android to servlet then using servlet we can insert the data or retrieve the data as your requirement

Please do the search above way definitely we can achieve your requirement ...

Regards
Kumar raja